# How to discard some messages for a window?

Tags: winapi, windows-messages, setwindowshookex

My goal is to disable some tool-tip-like thing in window of another process. My thoughts are to block `WM_MOUSEMOVE` if the coordinates of mouse movement is in certain rectangle of the window.

I can use `SetWindowsHookEx` to receive that messages (`WH_CALLWNDPROC` and `WH_GETMESSAGE`), but it doesn't allow to block them. I can return 1 instead of calling `CallNextHookEx`, but it doesn't prevent WndProc of window to receive the message. However, this approach works for blocking events in MOUSE_LL/KEYBOARD_LL.

`SetWindowsHookEx` is also not good, because it installs hook to all windows across the system.

How I can prevent window of another process from receiving certain windows messages?

Comment: Is the "tooltip-like thing" a top-level window? In this case you could block creation or hide window by using a `WH_CBT` hook.

Comment: It is inside of electron window, so the tooltip is not a window in terms of winapi.

Comment: You can't block the message but you can modify it. So just change `lpMsg->message`  to `WM_NULL`.

Comment: If you want to disable (standard) Tooltips, you can just send **TTM_ACTIVATE** (tested on Windows 10 with _EnumThreadWindows_ to find Tooltips of an external app)

Comment: @JonathanPotter, this works, thanks.This should be a marked answer for my question. Just don't forget to specify that only `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook can modify messages.

Comment: If your problem is solved, it's best to post an answer instead of comments.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT I can do it by my own, but it is answer of JonathanPotter. He should post it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Could you please post an answer instead of comments so that it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WH_GETMESSAGE` message hook doesn't let you "block" or cancel the message but you can modify it. So simply change `lpMsg->message` to `WM_NULL` to prevent the mouse move message from being processed by the target window.